# Is this network design a candidate for improved preformance from non-blocking NIO?

Tags: java, multithreading, io, connection-pooling, nio

I have a generic turn-based game I'm working on and currently here is how it operates:
Using boneCP (connection pool), MySQL database, java server, android client, and soon a thread-pool.

Client makes request to server.
Java serverspawns a new thread to process request.
Server sends response.
TCP socket terminates.

Rather than maintaining loads of persistent (long lasting) connections each client simple pokes the server every (x) interval and asks if it is their turn yet. If no, it does nothing. If yes it can input and send it's move to the server.

With this type of server-prodding networking, might I find some benefit in converting everything to NIO? The client's typically only send very small pieces of data, a few lines of text over TCP socket. The server could rarely and occasionally be sending larger files to clients (images, sound, video). Any other thoughts on using IO/NIO for this application? I wonder if this might expand my scalability by removing a bottleneck at max # of threads created, even if they do only last a second or so.

Edit: Also note: if player A waits more than 30-60 seconds to make their turn, then their turn is forfeit. So it's not as if I'm poking server in an infinite loop potentially forever. At best it would be intervals of 5 seconds a few times. And there's an upper bound on how many turn-forfeits before a game forfeit.

Comment: If you need to limit concurrency, use a thread pool instead of spawning a thread per request (see ExecutorService). I can't see any benefits on using NIO in your use case (most connections are short lived). However, I would consider using another service and network prioritization for serving those large files

Comment: A server can't use a connection pool. Only a client can use a connection pool. Your statement about 'not maintaining loads of persistent connections' contradicts your assertion about connection pooling. Your actual question remains obscure,

Comment: My server implements a connection pool and by persistent I mean rather than two players keeping their connections to the server till the end of their game, they send brief requests that get an instant response and then ends the connection/thread

Comment: If your server implements a connection pool, it is to some other resource, such as a database, that you haven't mentioned here yet. It doesn't implement a connection pool to the clients, which is the only thing you have mentioned so far. Possibly you mean a *collection* of connections to the clients. It's not the same thing.

Comment: I'm using BoneCP on a java server that spawns a new thread per connection (Soon in a thread-pool), and some of these end up doing MySQL interactions.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest an event-based method instead of such synchronous approach.

Instead of checking the client thousands of times in a while loop, you may check it in an event-loop which is much more efficient and scalable.

Comment: I left out an important detail.  If a player has not made their turn within say, 30 seconds, they lose that turn.  And so player B need only check if it is their turn several times, once every 5 or so seconds.

Comment: What you did is correct and 'seems' efficient. But imagine: your server is hosting a million games (maybe two million players), consequently, millions of threads are created and millions of operations are executed within every five seconds (sometimes for nothing but checking the nothing); You are asking about the scalability.

Comment: So is that more or less scalable than maintaining persistent connections between 2 million players?  
Sort of why I was thinking NIO might work better here but then the question still remains.  Prodding, or persistent?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid max threads bottleneck you could use a thread pool. You could do this by using NIO 2 async IO classes.

```
class ConnectionConext {}

class Handler implements CompletionHandler<Integer,ConnectionConext > {
public void completed(Integer result, ConnectionConext conn) {
// handle result
}
public void failed(Throwable exc, ConnectionConext conn) {
// error handling
}
}

//using executor's thread pool
ExecutorService executor = ...
//consider other withFixedThreadPool, or withCachedThreadPool
AsynchronousChannelGroup group = AsynchronousChannelGroup
.withThreadPool(executor);

AsynchronousSocketChannel channel =
AsynchronousSocketChannel.open(group);

ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(...);//consider to use ByteBuffer pool for better scalability
ConnectionConext conn = ..//some connection info that will be passed to completion handler.
Handler handler = ...

ch.read(buf, conn, handler);
```

Also consider [Grizzly Project](https://grizzly.java.net/) for useful stuff.

Comment: Also forgot to mention I'll be adding a thread pool soon as well.  So the real question is even with a thread pool, is NIO still offer more here than IO? I'll check that out Grisley soon as I wake up.

Comment: NIO's async IO is more suitable for heavy-loaded server application. So, if spawning thread-per-client is very costly for planned workload,then use combination of NIO thread pools and optionally buffer pools.